# Scalable Websockets - I am confused

Tags: angularjs, laravel, websocket

I've been googling it, and I'm a little confused about this. Pretty much everything I've read about it has 1 use-case but it doesn't seem like the best to me. Maybe it is though? Not sure.

Let me set the environment first:
The frontend is powered by AngularJS
An two backend APIs powered by Laravel (we'll call them A & B).

Now, all 3 of those scale independently of each other. And each one is in it's own docker container. There are load-balancers in front of each thing that handles routing and everything. I am using RDS for my database.

Now, the way I normally see, is to use a hash-ip thing for the loadbalancer, so that you just stay connected to the server that deals with whatever websocket events you need.

Well, that doesn't really seem like what I want. Really, long-polling seems like what I want, but I thought maybe I could get websockets to work. Basically, anytime ANYONE changes anything on either of the APIs, an event is fired. Then I need ALL of the frontends to update. Now as far as I understand, websockets use redis to keep track of events.

If it does use redis, how do you scale redis to be on multiple servers? Or would using something like elasticache be easier and then I just don't have to deal with that part?

Is all of this basically true? Am I on the right track with my thinking?

Thanks for taking a look. Sorry if it's a little ramble'y or confused. I am still not clear on it so everything I wrote is kind of just my thoughts.

Comment: webSockets by themselves have nothing to do with redis.  There is a mult-server implemention of socket.io (which uses webSockets) that uses redis for storage of state.  In that implementation, there is a central redis repository that all servers involved in the scaling can consult in order to communicate with users that may be connected to a different server.  You can read about the redis/socket.io combination [here](http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/).

Comment: I figured it out. There were just a couple extra steps I wasn't seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I'll post the answer for anyone else who happens to stumble across this.

All of this scales independently like I needed. But it is a little confusing, and I'm using Docker, so my answer will kind of involve that too.

So on Laravel, I just setup Events. They're being sent to a redis server on Redis Labs.

On my frontend docker, there is an AngularJS app, and also the websocket.js server is running via node on port 3000. On the container, there is Nginx serving them, the AngularJS deal is just a normal server directive. The one for the node, is a proxy pass directory, so that port 80 works normal, but it is forwarded to port 3000 on the backend.

The websocket.js server side part, connects to the same redis server on Redis Labs.

The AngularJS app is the one using the websockets client code.

Now there is another docker container running an nginx service that does loadbalancing. So, the loadbalancer is the one that all the websockets, api and frontend URLs go through.

It could be better to put the websocket.js into it's own container and scale it independently. But, right now, I think scaling the frontend and the websocket.js together will work well enough.

That is the overview of how I did it. I also used a lot of the stuff from here:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/step-by-step-guide-to-installing-socketio-and-broadcasting-events-with-laravel-51

and

https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-nodejs-websockets-socketio/